# How to get data from each dynamically created EditText in Android?

Tags: java, android, string, android-edittext

I have successfully created EditTexts depending on the user input in Android, and also I have assigned them  unique ID's using `setId()` method.

Now what I want to do is to get values from the dynamically created `EditText`s when the user tap a button, then store all of them in String variables. i.e. value from EditText having id '1' should be saved in str1 of type String, and so on depending on the number of EditTexts.

I am using `getid()`, and `gettext().toString()` methods but it seems a bit tricky... I cannot assign each value of EditText to a String variable. When I try to do that a `NullPointerException` occurs, and if it is not the case where no user input data is shown, I display it in a toast.

Heres, the code:

```
EditText ed;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {   

        ed = new EditText(Activity2.this);
        ed.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blackOpacity);
        ed.setId(id);   
        ed.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        linear.addView(ed);

}
```

How do I now pass the value from each EditText to each different string variable? If some body could help with a sample code it would be nice.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In every iteration you are rewriting the `ed` variable, so when loop is finished `ed` only points to the last EditText instance you created.

You should store all references to all EditTexts:

```
EditText ed;
List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {   

    ed = new EditText(Activity2.this);
    allEds.add(ed);
    ed.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blackOpacity);
    ed.setId(id);   
    ed.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    linear.addView(ed);
}
```

Now `allEds` list hold references to all EditTexts, so you can iterate it and get all the data.

**Update:**

As per request:

```
String[] strings = new String[](allEds.size());

for(int i=0; i < allEds.size(); i++){
    string[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: Can you please also help me on retrieve and save values from allEds to string array too .. tat would be so nice (:

Comment: Thanks much appreciate, but i would like you to consider the below statement again as im getting an assignment error in this: Left hand side must be a variable?

String[] strings = new String[](allEds.size());

Comment: My bad. Should be ` String[] strings = new String[allEds.size()];`

Comment: @Peter Knego your answer has been copied here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102773/get-the-value-of-dynamically-generated-multiple-edittext-using-gettext-in-androi/16102950#16102950 By gowtham I have complained to moderator please tahe necessary steps.

Comment: Hey can you please clear that what we used as id here, I am little bit confused. I am getting empty values from edittext.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. It works perfect for my problem!

Answer (score 4):

You can also do like this by taking an Array of EditText.
You should store all references to all EditTexts:

```
EditText ed[] = new EditText[count];    
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {   

    ed[i] = new EditText(Activity2.this);

    ed[i].setBackgroundResource(R.color.blackOpacity);
    ed[i].setId(id);   
    ed[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    linear.addView(ed[i]);
}
```

and you can use for loop to get the value from the EditText .

```
 for(int i = 0; i < ed.length; i++){

       Log.d("Value ","Val " + ed[i].getText());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a for loop generating dynamic TextViews within TableRows from a JSON string. Here's what I did:

```
// Generate Dynamic tablerows and set a unique id
//m_jArry is a JSON Array

for(int i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++)
{
    jo_inside = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);
    TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext())
    row.setId(jo_inside.getInt("id"));
    ...        
    findViewById(row.getId())
    ...
}
```

I am using findViewById(row.getId()) to set the dynamic TextView text data to EditText fields in my app. For those of you who do not understand JSON, there are several good tutorials out there (I'm sure there are great explanations here on Stack Overflow) for the Android platform. I'm still an Android newbie, but I hope this is helpful to some of you out there.

Answer (score 1):

```
            String[] strings = new String[allEds.size()];
            String[] strings1 = new String[allEdn.size()];

            for(int i=0; i < allEds.size(); i++){
                strings[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();
                strings1[i] = allEdn.get(i).getText().toString();
                System.out.println("data in edittext name is  " +strings[i]);
                System.out.println("data in edittext number is " +strings1[i]);
            }
```

for multiple edittext

Answer (score 0):

this is because EditText.gettext() return Editable , so toString will not work .
try String.valueOf(edittext.gettext) .

if u sure that u r getting d right EditText but prob. is how 2 pass its test to string den
code is

```
    EditText t = new EditText(this);
    t.setText("test");// obviously in ur case it will be intered by user
    String s = String.valueOf(t.getText());
    System.out.println(s);
```

else use setTeg(Edittext) n get editText by getTag on button click .

Comment: Well shailendra, it was about the correct reference of edittexts .. i was getting value from only last referenced edittext 
your code might come handy some other day hehe Thanks for help :)