# How to get values from dynamically created EditText fields?

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, android-edittext

I am little confused with following scenario:

I have an add button which I use it to add a number of `EditText` fields, when I tap on the save button I should get the values from the `EditText`s.

How can I get these values from all of the EditText fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

Store all the EditText fields you create programmatically inside a List. So whenever you have `viewGroup.add(myEditText);` you would also have `myList.add(myEditText);`

Then when you press 'save' just loop on your list and use `getText()` to get the data from your EditText fields.

I'm sure there are also other ways to accomplish this ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923587/how-to-get-data-from-each-dynamically-created-edittext-in-android   i think the solution i s here :)

Comment: yep that's exactly what I was suggesting ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
btn_no_of.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String str1=edittext1.gettext.tostring();
                            String str2=edittext2.gettext.tostring();

        }
    });
```

Comment: I created edittext dynamically, number of text field is unknown