# How to take values from dynamically created EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Here I have created EdiIexts dynamically by clicking the button, how can I take values from these EditTexts? I have seen many examples but I am unable to get values!

```
 final LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(this);
 ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
 Button add_btn=new Button(this);
 add_btn.setText("Click to add TextViiews and EditTexts");
 ll.addView(add_btn);     

 add_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {     
     public void onClick(View v) {

         EditText et=new EditText(getApplicationContext());

         ll.addView(et);
```

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923587/how-to-get-data-from-each-dynamically-created-edittext-in-android

Comment: [Answer] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506849/how-to-get-values-from-dynamically-created-edittext-fields/40995882#40995882

Comment: [Answer] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506849/how-to-get-values-from-dynamically-created-edittext-fields/40995882#40995882

Answer (score 2):

You can get dynamically created edittext's value the same way you would do with edittext of .xml file.

```
String value;
add_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                value = et.getText().toString();
            }
        });
```

Comment: TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);  
 EditText et2=new EditText(getApplicationContext());
 
 String s=et2.getText().toString();
 tv.setText(s);
 ll.addView(et2);

Comment: @user1940822, What is this? Are you having some other problem?

Comment: ok but how can i display the value? i have used tv1.settext(value); where tv is textview i have created TextView tv1=(TextView)findviewbyid(R.id.tv); but i am getting force close.

Comment: @user1940822 Please show your new code and logcat error in your question by editing it

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
 String str;
  TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);  
       EditText et2=new EditText(getApplicationContext());
  String s=et2.getText().toString();  
  tv.setText(s);
ll.addView(et2); 
}
 });

Comment: @user1940822, Please post logcat output of crash

Comment: 01-11 17:31:17.996: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at com.app.DynamicbuttonActivity$1.onClick(DynamicbuttonActivity.java:43)

Comment: -11 17:31:17.996: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

Comment: @user1940822, copy whole logcat crash output and paste it in your question. You can edit your question by using edit link below it

Comment: android.app.ActivityThread.main

(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at 

java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native 

Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at 

java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at 

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit

$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at 

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main

(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at 

dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity 

com.app/.DynamicbuttonActivity

Comment: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout for 
HistoryRecord{44f2cd78 

com.app/.DynamicbuttonActivity}
W/ActivityManager(59): Activity destroy timeout 

for HistoryRecord{44f2cd78 

com.app/.DynamicbuttonActivity} E/AndroidRuntime

(546):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit

$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868) here i have sent all the log cat in 2 posts

Comment: @user1940822, If you post the logcat or code in comment, it would not be so understandable. That's why I am telling you to EDIT your original question

Comment: i have tried but i am unable to post it is giving me this errorOops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:

Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Answer (score 2):

add this code where you want to get the edittext's value

```
 EditText et2=(EditText)ll.getChildAt(l1.getChildCount()); //make sure to create new edittext variable do not use "et"
 String s=et2.getText().toString();
```

Comment: i am getting error when i am using EditText et2=(EditText)ll.getChildAt(getChildCount); i getting error at getChildCount  and also i am trying to display the values can you please help me

Comment: i have tried but i am not getting k k how we know that it is taking our values so if we display the values we can know so i am trying to display using textview.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `EditText et` as a **Class level Member variables** for your Activity,

```
private EditText et = null;
```

Now, in Button's onClick

```
add_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {     
 public void onClick(View v) {
     et = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
     ll.addView(et);
```

Now, you can get the `EditText et` values any where in your Activity scope, using

```
if(et != null)
String value = et.getText().toString();
```

Comment: where should i write if condition and how can we display the values

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
LinearLayout linearLayoutForm = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutForm);
EditText edit = (EditText) linearLayoutForm.findViewById(id);
String value = edit.getText().toString();
```