# How to get data from dynamically created EditText using LayoutInflater in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-relativelayout, layout-inflater

## This is Relative Layout view which is created dynamically like this :

### [image: Layout]

...
So my question is how to get the values from those dynamic elements and perform some calculation to show result on textview which is also dynamically created.
Thanks in advance guys!!

```
    public void goButtonClicked(View view) {
    maalContainer.removeAllViews();
    int numberofPlayersTolayout = (Integer) Integer.parseInt((String) numberOfPlayers.getSelectedItem());

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberofPlayersTolayout; i++) {
        View dynamicEntryView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player_entry_item, null);
        maalContainer.addView(dynamicEntryView, params);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: set Id to `dynamicEntryView` and save all Id then get value with Id's of `dynamicEntryView`

Comment: [Answer] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506849/how-to-get-values-from-dynamically-created-edittext-fields/40995882#40995882

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     public void goButtonClicked(View view) {
         int numberofPlayersTolayout =       Integer.parseInt(numberOfPlayers.getSelectedItem().toString());
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        maalContainer.removeAllViews();

        maalText = new EditText[numberofPlayersTolayout];
        points = new EditText[numberofPlayersTolayout];
        result = new TextView[numberofPlayersTolayout];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberofPlayersTolayout; i++) {
            View dynamicEntryView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player_entry_item, null);
            maalContainer.addView(dynamicEntryView, params);
            TextView playerName = (TextView) dynamicEntryView.findViewById(R.id.player_name_textview);
            playerName.setText("Player :" + (i + 1));

            maalText[i] = (EditText) dynamicEntryView.findViewById(R.id.player_item_edittext_maal);
            points[i] = (EditText) dynamicEntryView.findViewById(R.id.player_item_edittext_point);
            result[i] = (TextView) dynamicEntryView.findViewById(R.id.player_item_textview_result);
}
```

Comment: I know it is very late, but can you please share the XML files? What I want to know is this - in the XML for the EDitText and TextView have you mentioned "android:id" field? If so, all the EditText in the rows will be having same id - correct? I am a little confused. Please help.

Comment: I have added xml in above fields. @user2731584

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I figured it out!

Answer (score 6):

```
for (int i = 0; i < maalContainer.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View view = maalContainer.getChildAt(i);

    EditText ed_item = (EditText) view
            .findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
    EditText ed_value = (EditText) view
            .findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
    EditText ed_value1 = (EditText) view
            .findViewById(R.id.edittext3);

    ed_item.getText().toString().trim();
    ed_value.getText().toString().trim();
    ed_value1.getText().toString().trim();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to assign/get ID of any View but the best way is to iterate through the child views of `LinearLayout`:

```
int childcount = myLinearLayout.getChildCount();
for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
      View v = myLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
    // do whatever you would want to do with this View
}
```

Comment: My LinearLayout consists of EditText1,2,3 for eg and the linear layout expands upto LinearLayout1..10 so I want to iterate through all the EditText and get data. THanks..

Answer (score 2):

A few things here:

1. You shouldn't be using the `Application` `Context` to get the `LayoutInflater`. You should get that from the `Activity` `Context`, otherwise your themes and styles will not be respected.
2. You shouldn't inflate with null as the second parameter (except in special instances where you don't know the `View`'s parent). Just put the `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` attributes in `player_entry_item.xml` and they will be respected upon inflation.
3. Store the `EditText` objects upon inflation as a private array.

With that said, my suggested revision:

```
private EditText[] mEditTextPlayers;

public void goButtonClicked(View view) {
    maalContainer.removeAllViews();
    int numPlayers = Integer.parseInt((String) numberOfPlayers.getSelectedItem());

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext());
    mEditTextPlayers = new EditText[numPlayers];

    for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
        //Pass the parent as the second parameter to retain layout attributes
        mEditTextPlayers[i] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player_entry_item, maalContainer, false);
        maalContainer.addView(dynamicEntryView);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's `mEditTextPlayers`. Instead of a local reference, it's a class reference containing all of the EditText objects that you inflated. You can then access each of them by their index (e.g. `mEditTextPlayers[0].getText().toString()`)

Comment: My player1 to nth player  has to display EditText1 EditText2 and TextView1 but your mEditTextPlayers is defined as EditText only. #kcoppock Thanks.

Comment: Then just make an array of arrays or some other mapping. EditText extends TextView so it could actually even just be an array of TextViews mod 3.

Comment: #kcoppock even when I use three edittext then also the code above did not work...it fails giving out error saying method cannot be executed... thanks for the help...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `getId()` and `setId()` methods of the View.

```
   dynamicEntryView.setId(i);
```

and access the view as below by getting the

```
   dynamicEntryView.getId(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/player_name_textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:text="Player name"
        android:textColor="#202020"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/player_item_edittext_point"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Points"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColor="#202020" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/player_item_edittext_maal"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Maal"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColor="#202020" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/player_item_textview_result"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0.00$"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:typeface="serif" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Only one id is used. It will loop through according to number of players. Hope it will help you. @user2731584