# get the value of dynamically generated multiple edittext using gettext in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want the text value set on multiple edittext, onclick of button. Edit text is generated dynamically and I want value of each particular edit text. And store that value of text in a string array.

```
if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Edittext")) {
                Question = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                        .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.QUESTIONS));
                String ID = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                        .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.ID));
                // ll_layout1 = (LinearLayout)
                // findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1);
                tv_edittext = new TextView(this);
                tv_edittext.setTextSize(20.0f);
                tv_edittext.setText(Question);
                ll_layout1.addView(tv_edittext);
                et = new EditText(this);
                et.setOnClickListener(this);
                et.setId(EDITTEXT);
                et.setMinLines(1);
                et.setMaxLines(3);
                // editTextList.add(et);
                ll_layout1.addView(et);
                // editTextList.add(et);

                typelist.add(Question);

            }
```

this code generate Text and edittext. How to start?

Comment: sorry but question not clear to me..

Comment: Although question is not clear, bt what I understood u cn refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923587/how-to-get-data-from-each-dynamically-created-edittext-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
tv_edittext = new MyTextView(this);
```

where MyTextView is :

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView{

    public SampleEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher());
    }

    public SampleEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher());
    }

    public SampleEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher());
    }

}
```

Use a textwatcher as follows:

```
public class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

}
```

No matter how many textviews you dynamically create, a watcher will be created for it and you can get the text being typed in the `onTextChanged` method of the textwatcher.