# android can't retrieve view by id after setting it dynamically

Tags: android, android-edittext

i am using ListFragment , and inside this fragment and in onCreate function i am using custom cursor adapter , that repeats my layout for a certain number of times ,
The layout contains some elements , and one of them is EditText,and i need to handle these EditText(s) latter .
 inside this adapter , i am changing the id of EditText dynamically 
like this way

```
//get EditText and give it the same id of dish 
     EditText  noteEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editTextNote);
     if (noteEditText != null){
            int record_ID_int = Integer.parseInt(record_ID);
            noteEditText.setId(record_ID_int);
            noteEditText.setText(""+record_ID_int);

                        EditText tempEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(record_ID_int);
            if (tempEditText != null){
                tempEditText.setText(""+record_ID_int);
                 Log.e("layout"," tempEditText is Not Not null after retriveing it by id :"+record_ID_int);
            }else{
                   Log.e("layout"," tempEditText is  null null null   by id  :"+record_ID_int);
            }           
        }
```

where editTextNote is the static id that is set in the layout 
as you can see , that i am performing another operation besides changing the id , i am setting the text also , so i can be sure that the operation is going well , and when i run the app , i can see that the text is set correctly.
 and inside this block of cursor adapter , the layout (v) is able to get the EditText by calling findViewById  on the just passed id

but when i am trying to retrieve these EditText by passing the same id to it , it return null !!! i put the code of retrieving EditText in the same fragment , in function onStart().
Note::i saved the id(s) that i had set to EditText in a SharedPreference , so in the following code i am retrieving the id(s) from SharedPreference , then passing them to function findViewById to get the required EditText 
code of retrieving editText component is :

```
  LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity(). getLayoutInflater();
   View myLayout =inflater.inflate(R.layout.display_order_list_layout, null, false);       
   View parentView =(View) myLayout.getRootView();

   if (myLayout != null){
       //1::get sharedPrefNotes from my classes 
        ManageOrder manageOrder = new ManageOrder(getActivity());
         int []  keysNotesArray = manageOrder.getAllSharedPreferenceNoteKeys();

        //below just a test to see it the layout can get other per-definned id's elements in layout 
         TextView  textView = (TextView) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.textViewTotalPriceThisDishStr);
         if (textView != null ){
             Log.e("layout","textView with id : textViewTotalPriceThisDishStr| text is : "+textView.getText()); 
         }else {
               Log.e("layout","textView is null ,id  textViewTotalPriceThisDishStr");
         }


         for (int i = 0 ; i<keysNotesArray.length; i++){

             int key_id = keysNotesArray[i];
             //2::find item by id 
             EditText  noteEditText = (EditText) myLayout.findViewById(key_id);
             if (noteEditText != null ){
                 Log.e("layout","EditText with id :"+key_id +"| text is : "+noteEditText.getText()); 
             }else {
                   Log.e("layout","EditText is null od id  "+key_id);
             }


         }

   }else {
       Log.e("layout","myLayout is null ");
   }
```

the log file show the following results

```
05-07 19:41:25.584: E/layout(5002): 114: 
05-07 19:41:25.584: E/layout(5002): 95: 
05-07 19:41:25.584: E/layout(5002): 75: 
05-07 19:41:25.584: E/layout(5002): 123: 
05-07 19:41:25.585: E/layout(5002): textView  with id : textViewTotalPriceThisDishStr| text is : الاجمالي
05-07 19:41:25.585: E/layout(5002): EditText is null , id  114
05-07 19:41:25.586: E/layout(5002): EditText is null , id  95
05-07 19:41:25.586: E/layout(5002): EditText is null , id  75
05-07 19:41:25.586: E/layout(5002): EditText is null , id  123
```

so what is the problem ??

Comment: Post the retrieving code as well. Also providing logcat for the same will help to solve your issue faster

Comment: i add the code in details and the logcat and i am waiting the answer

Comment: [Check out this link.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5923764/2345913) May be this will help

Comment: when you inflate `View myLayout` in above mentioned code myLayout gets assign id's mentioned in layout.xml. So follow the link provided above to solve the problem

Comment: thanks , it works
Thanks it works :)
but now i have another problem , i can not have real focus on editText when i have more than one editText in the same layout. whenever i put the cursor in a editText then move to keyboard , the focus goes from that editText !!!