# The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant)

Tags: android

i am new to Android and i might have a silly / dumb Question. I have got an Activity where i want to dynamically create Multiple Input Fields. The amount of Input Fields is defined by the User.

Because the Input is Styled and Consists of 2 Elements and didnt want to Create these Elements every Time because of Elements have got multiple Parameters that are the same every time. Thats why i created a XML File just for this two Elements which i would like to use in my Programm to Create the Inputs.

View_input.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:parentTag="androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutTableName"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/create_table_name"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:placeholderText="@string/create_table_table_name_placeholder"
        app:startIconTintMode="src_in">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textInputName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</merge>
```

My Target XML (**activity_create_table_column_names.xml**) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout         
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.createtable.CreateTableColumnNamesActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/columnNameInputContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/create_table_column_names"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- HERE --> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Where i wrote `<!-- HERE -->`i want all my Input-Fields to be.

I started with just displaying one Input:

```
private fun initLayout() {
    val container = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.columnNameInputContainer)
    val inflater = applicationContext
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_input, LinearLayout(this))
    container.addView(view)
}
```

But i got the Following Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:243)
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:217)
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:145)
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:115)
at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:458)
at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:417)
```

My Styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
        ...
    </style>
</resources>
```

What am i doing wrong? Is this even the correct way i should programm something like this?

***Edit***: 
**Android.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="de.hsos.ma.adhocdb">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.createtable.CreateTableColumnNamesActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.homescreen.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.createtable.CreateTableActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.homescreen.MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.homescreen.TestTableActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.homescreen.MainActivity">

            <!--
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            -->
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.TableShow.TableShowActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.homescreen.MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ui.tablelist.LayoutTableListItem" />
        <activity android:name=".ui.homescreen.MainActivity">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you post your `AndroidManifest.xml` content

Comment: @MohammedAlaa yes i added the manifest at the bottom of my post

Answer (score 10, accepted):

found the solution ,get your inflator from activity not application just modify your `initLayout()` like this

```
// here is the fix
val inflater = getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
```

Comment: that worked thanks!!!  @MohammedAlaa do you know how i can read the text of the different inputs ("@+id/textInputName") if i create multiple inputs?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923587/how-to-get-data-from-each-dynamically-created-edittext-in-android) it's the same, also if the answer helped you ,you can accept it so when others search for the same issue they can find the solution

Comment: thanks for your time! i just added all the textviews in an array while creating the view and that worked for me!

Comment: Firstly thanks for your time. 

I change my layout inflation from
    ```LayoutInflater.from(baseContext).inflate(it, null)``` 
to 

```val inflater = getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            val inflatedView = inflater.inflate(it, null)```

Comment: I actually just needed to create my view with the activity context instead of the application context. This answer helped me figure it out, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

just set the theme on the chip itself  using **android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Bridge**:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      *****android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Bridge"****
    style="@style/CustomFiltersChipChoice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:chipStrokeColor="#F0F"
    app:chipStrokeWidth="1dp"
    app:textEndPadding="10dp"
    app:textStartPadding="10dp"
    tools:chipText="my chip"
    tools:text="Fortune" />
```

Comment: There is one problem with this. The question does not include Chip at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your view to change and with on tool bar try this,

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar.Bridge"/>
```