# Fetch data from dynamically created TextInputEditText and insert them to an array

Tags: android

Currently I have added the dynamic `TextInputEditText` fields to the LinearLayout where all the dynamically added fields stores(only holds dynamic EditText fields only).

However, when I read each `EditText` field and fetch it's data, the value of last text field replace all the other values in the array.


**Example:**
Adds 3 dynamic fields, with the corresponding values of "AA","BB","CC". When i read the array, it shows like this,

**Output**: "CC,CC,CC"

**Code:**

```
private void fetchCertificates(){

    ArrayList<String> certs = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i =0;i<linearLayout.getChildCount();i++){

        View certificateView = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);

        TextInputEditText newCerts = findViewById(R.id.new_certs);
        String name = newCerts.getText().toString();
        certs.add(name);
    }

    String certList = android.text.TextUtils.join(",", certs);
    Log.i("Certificates",certs);
}
```

**Objective:**
Read dynamically added TextInputEditText, and store the values in an array.

**References**: [page-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923587/how-to-get-data-from-each-dynamically-created-edittext-in-android) (This did not work)

Comment: You are doing nothing with the childs `certificateView`.

Comment: TextInputEditText newCerts = findViewById(R.id.new_certs);
 the "newCerts" always contains your "CC" string, need to use certificateView.getText().toString()

Comment: Hi that was my initial idea, however when i use `getText()` on `certificateView`, it says "cannot resolve method getText in View"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve it in following way, thanks for the questioning hellboy and blackapps, it made me think bit differently.

private void fetchCertificates(){

```
ArrayList<String> certs = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i =0;i<linearLayout.getChildCount();i++){

    View certificateView = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);

    TextInputEditText newCerts = certificateView.findViewById(R.id.new_certs);
    String name = newCerts.getText().toString();
    certs.add(name);
}

String certList = android.text.TextUtils.join(",", certs);
Log.i("Certificates",certs);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is at these lines,

```
    View certificateView = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
    TextInputEditText newCerts = findViewById(R.id.new_certs);
```

Assuming that the LinearLayout(parent) carries only TextInputEditText(children), when you iterate through LinearLayout you will get TextInputEditText only, so your code should be like,

```
    View certificateView = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
    TextInputEditText newCerts = (TextInputEditText) certificateView;
```

or

```
    TextInputEditText newCerts = (TextInputEditText) linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
```

In your code since you directly used `findViewById` you always got the last to the latest view(child) with this id(remember if there are multiple views with the same id, then the latest view defined, both in Activity or layout, will be fetched) that's the reason you get CC, CC, CC.